# graphicsmagic compare the opacity of the diff image

Tags: graphicsmagick

If I do the following on the command line:

```
compare out1.png out2.png diff\out1.png
```

The diff image is very light and it's easy to spot the differences (even if they are only a couple of pixels).

I can't seem to get the same result using gm:

```
gm compare -colorspace GRAY -highlight-color red -verbose -file 
   diff\out1.png out1.png out2.png
```

This will have the red difference stick out a little but the resulting image is not transparent (alpha opacity?) like with the compare command. I think compare came from installing graphicsmagick so it uses gm but with what parameters?

**[UPDATE]**

I just found that compare.exe is from Imagemagic

Answer (score 0):

The reason I needed this is because I was using [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) with [webdriverjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) (selenium-webdriver for node) to compare my dev environment with the production/staging site.

Because [gm.compare did not work](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/517) with imagemagick I used graphicsmagick but solving the bug with gm was easier than trying to figure out how to use graphicsmagick.

So even though the actual question is not answered I solved the problem.

Maybe I'll turn this question into a wiki for webdriverjs.